# Header redirect advert die() OR exit() when using script to write to file

Tags: php

I have made a small script which dynamically created a text file and then downloads it to the users computer when then press a download button... the entire script below is what runs when the user presses 'download'

```
<?php 

    if (isset($_GET['download'])) {
        if ($_GET['download'] == "1") {


            header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=TEST - Backup.txt');
            header('Content-type: text/plain');



            $projects = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE user_id = '$user_id' ORDER BY id ASC"; 
            if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$projects)) {
                while ($projects_array=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 


                    $sql = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM refs WHERE project_id = " . $projects_array['id']);
                    $row = $sql->fetch_row();
                    $count = $row[0];

                    echo "\n\n" . "=== " . $projects_array['project_name'] . " ===" . "\n\n";


                    if ($count > 0) {
                        $all = "SELECT * FROM refs WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND project_id = " . $projects_array['id'] . " ORDER BY IF(a_s_name = '', company_a, a_s_name) ASC"; 
                        if ($result_a=mysqli_query($conn,$all)) {
                            while ($ref=mysqli_fetch_array($result_a)) {    
                                include 'sections/get.php';
                                if ($ref['type'] == 1){
                                    include 'refs/1.php'; 
                                } elseif ($ref['type'] == 2) {
                                    include 'refs/2.php'; 
                                } elseif ($ref['type'] == 3) {
                                    include 'refs/3.php'; 
                                }

                                echo "\t" . strip_tags($cit) . "\n";
                                echo "\t" . strip_tags($ref) . "\n\n";

                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "\t" . "You don't currently have any references for this project." . "\n\n";
                    }

                }
            }
            die ();


        }
    }

?>
```

After the user has pressed the download button, currently the file is download, however I want the user to then be redirected to a new location on the site.

I attempted to do this by using header location along with die();... so I replaced die() with this below:

```
die (header ("Location: http://siteurl.co.uk/?suc=8"));
```

However using this the file is not downloaded however the user is redirected

I appreciate any help

Comment: This isn't possible. If the script performs a redirect, the data is ignored. So you can either redirect or download, not both.

Comment: Okay, so there is absolutely no way to do a redirect after a file is downloaded ? - a down vote is pretty mean, I am now banned from asking questions

Comment: I didn't downvote, I just commented.

Comment: Thankyou for your comment

Comment: You can use Javascript to open a new window that performs the download and then redirects the original window.

Comment: @Bamar This would be a good option, please could you suggest this as an answer. I have just looked into doing a JS popup window however cannot find a simple way of adding it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156297/discussion-between-bradley-cousins-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Javascript to open a popup window that performs the download, then it redirects the original window.

```
window.open("yourscript.php?download=1");
window.location.href = "http://siteurl.co.uk/?suc=8";
```

Comment: window.open only opens a new tab, is there a popup window solution ?

Comment: Whether it opens a tab or window is a browser settings option, not controllable from the script.